# HTML5 Video Does Not Play on iOS over HTTPS when deployed to Firebase Hosting

Tags: ios, html, firebase, https, hosting

I am using the the HTML5 Video tag on a PWA created in angular 6 and for the life of me I can't get it to work. At first I thought it was an issue with encoding since it works on FF, Chrome (Desktop and Mobile), and Safari Desktop. I have checked the encoding and the use of the video tag. I believe that all is in order. **I am able to play the video on iOS when serving it using HTTP from my local.**

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

It fails to play when trying to use HTTPS and a cert generated from openssl.

```
http-server dist/marcel-webapp/ -S
```

This leads me to believe that the issue is only with untrusted certificates. The problem that I having a very hard time finding the solution to is that I am hosting it on Firebase, and google handles the provisioning of the SSL certificates automatically. I checked my version of the trust store on my phone and the neither the root or intermediate certificates in use are listed.

[Here is the link to the video my site](https://msfd.info/video/riverstone)

The question is... If really do have a certificate issue on firebase, what can be do about it?

Thanks in advance for any guidance on this.

Comment: This is an angular PWA, no Info.plist

Answer (score 1):

Update and actual problem identified! I eliminated an untrusted certificate as the problem by deploying to AWS. The problem is actually related to the service worker created when adding PWA support to the project. The reason the video works over HTTP is that service workers are only enabled in HTTPS. I'm using Angular 6 to create the PWA, however it seems that other frameworks have the same problem. Turning off services workers in the Safari allows the video to display as expected

**Settings > Safari > Advanced > Experimental Features > Service Workers**

I found this post describes the problem in great detail. [View Post Here](https://philna.sh/blog/2018/10/23/service-workers-beware-safaris-range-request/)